# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, express, ts-node, npm-run

I'm trying to run a node server using:
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/ng serve  --proxy-config ./proxy.json"
and I'm getting the error of:
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I must say it worked perfectly for a while, and it started to appear recently,
after some other installations on my machine, ie python...

If I do it with full path:
"server": "c:/dev/my-working-folder/node_modules/.bin/ts-node -P ./server/server.tsconfig.json ./server/server.ts"
it will work.

I'll Appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the full error output? Can you tell exactly where the error is coming from? This sounds like maybe a shell script that is trying to use `. foo` as a shorthand for `source foo`?

Comment: Node scripts typically run with the `.bin` directory in the path so you can probably use `"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.json"`

Comment: This is the whole error: 
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

On another Node app I now get: 
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command npm run start" terminated with exit code: 1.

Thanks.